# Como alterar a imagem de fundo de um WxDialog?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Como faço para usar uma imagem como *background* de um `wxDialog`? 
Usando o `WxStaticBitmap`, os componentes não aparecem direito. Estou utilizando a versão 2.8.12 do [WxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/).

Exemplo de resultado esperado:
[image: imagem]

Comment: Qual o problema que vc está vendo nos componentes ? parece normal pra mim.

Comment: O wxButton não está exibido corretamente. O botão está retangular, quando ele possui bordas arredondadas...

Comment: Veja se isso resolve: button->SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_TRANSPARENT)

Comment: Funcionaria, mas estou com a versão 2.8.12, que ainda não tem wxBG_STYLE_TRANSPARENT.

Comment: e assim ? button->SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_CUSTOM)

Comment: Fica do mesmo jeito.

Comment: em qual SO vc está trabalhando e pq usar a versão 2.8 ?

Comment: Windows 7, pois só achei wxLua para 2.8.12, e eu uso Lua.

Answer (score 1):

Não faz. Essa versão de wxWidgets que vc está usando é bem antiga. Até onde sei, todo o desenvolvimento está concentrado nas versões 3.0+. Essa versão 2.8 que está usando não vai mais receber melhorias. Elas foram feitas nas versões mais recentes. 
Se a linguagem Lua que está usando ainda está usando essa versão e vc não tem outra opção, o jeito é se adaptar a ela. Tipo usar uma imagem de fundo que tenha cores que se adaptem aos buttons. Especialmente pq essa função que vc quer só está disponível em Gtk (ambiente Gnome pra GNU/Linux). Como vc pode ler aqui:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8.12/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowsetbackgroundstyle

> "On GTK+, use of wxBG_STYLE_CUSTOM allows the flicker-free drawing of
>   a custom background, such as a tiled bitmap. Currently the style has
>   no effect on other platforms."
>
> **Tradução:** "No GTK+, o uso de wxBG_STYLE_CUSTOM permite o desenho de um
>   fundo customizado, como um bitmap ladrilhado. Atualmente o estilo não
>   tem efeito em outras plataformas."

Comment: Trocar a imagem de fundo é uma boa idéa também pq é uma sacanagem usar uma foto de pinguins como imagem de fundo de uma aplicação Windows :D KKK